# How to get VirtualFile from a VirtualFile URL in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am working on plugin in on IntelliJ.

Now I have a `VirtualFile file`, I am trying to write `file.getUrl()` to local file system so that I can get `file` back when I restart my plugin. But It seems I can not get the `VirtualFile` from a `url`?

Comment: Does this work? `LocalFileSystem.getInstance().findFileByPath(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a file by URL, use `VirtualFileManager.findFileByUrl()` ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/vfs/VirtualFileManager.java#L94)). Or keep things simple, store the path and use `LocalFileSystem.findFileByPath()` as suggested by @vikingsteve.

Answer (score 0):

```
 VirtualFile[] vFiles = ProjectRootManager.getInstance(this.project).getContentRoots();
 VirtualFile stateMachineConfig = vFiles[0].findChild("stateConfig.json");
```